# Clicking on "Go get it" for tag badge takes me to a different page

Tags: support, question-lists, custom-questions-list

Recently, when clicking on "Go get it" on the silver JavaScript tag badge, I have been taken to the questions page as per usual, but instead of the filters being `No accepted answer` and `Newest`, which they were quite recently, they have a new default: `No accepted answer` and `Most votes`. Is there any way I can set the filters back to the default `Newest`, or is this a bug?

Comment: I think this is a new bug/feature of [Custom Questions List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323202/241919).

Comment: "It's the journey that counts, not the destination" - Cavaphis :)